# How can I disable background widgets in flutter

Tags: flutter

What I want to achieve is like when you use the alert dialog widget :
[image]

When the dialog box shows everything in the background is darkened and disabled. I want to do that but I don't want to use a dialogbox , I have a Container that slides from the bottom of the screen, it's inside a Stack widget.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: That's not my question

Comment: `showDialog(
    barrierColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0),
    barrierDismissible: false,
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return WillPopScope(
            onWillPop: (){},
          child: alert);`

Comment: I'm not using a dialog box, it's a Form inside a Container

Comment: You want to use your custom alert dialog which it is your container widget right ?

Comment: call `showDialog` with `builder` returning your `Container` - it does not have to be `Dialog` / `AlertDialog` / `SimpleDialog` widgets

Comment: I tried used this showDialog, but it seems like it creates a new context scope, and I lose access to the Providers I've initiliazed in the main.dart, also the background is just white. Seems like it creates a whole different widget tree.

Comment: see https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple#changenotifierprovider - they say: *"But in our case, the only widget that is on top of both MyCart and MyCatalog is MyApp."*

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your widget with `Scaffold` and set the `backgroundColor` to

```
 // change the color as you like
    backgroundColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),
```